# Edit specific item from list

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to ask how I can edit the item from the collection. For example: In the collection myList I (string name, DateTime Event). I would like to make the event moved to the next year.

I tried:

```
 public class ClassEvent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

 public ClassEvent(string name, DateTime date)
        {

            Name = name;
            Date = date;
        }
```

Myclass:

```
public List<ClassEvent> event= new List<ClassEvent>();
public void AddEvent(string name, DateTime MyEvent)
        {
            ClassEvent  ev = new ClassEvent(name, MyEvent.Date);
            event.Add(ev);
        }
```

MainForm:

```
forach( var a in MyClass.event)
{
   if(a.MyEvent == DateTime.Today)
      {
           Myclass.AddEvent(a.name, a.MyEvent.AddYears(1);
}
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: Post the `ClassEvent` definition

Comment: enumerations in foreach loops are immutable, they can only be read. Use a for loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify collection within *foreach* loop. Use *for* loop isntead:

To ***add*** new items into the collection:

```
  // Pay attention: backward loop
  for(int i = MyClass.event.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    ClassEvent a = MyClass.event[i];

    if (a.MyEvent == DateTime.Today)
      Myclass.AddEvent(a.name, a.MyEvent.AddYears(1);
  }
```

To ***change*** existing items in the collection:

```
  // Any direction forward/backward will do
  for(int i = MyClass.event.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    ClassEvent a = MyClass.event[i];

    // Just change "a", since "a" is a item in the collection already
    //TODO: Check the syntax; "MyEvent" is expected being a writeable property 
    if (a.MyEvent == DateTime.Today)  
      a.MyEvent = a.MyEvent.AddYears(1);
  }
```

Comment: While you're correct, I believe OP need to edit the existing item rather than adding new

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new ClassEvent in your foreach loop and you are not editing the one you are on. I would try:

```
forach( var a in MyClass.event)
{
  if(a.MyEvent == DateTime.Today)
   {
     a.MyEvent.AddYears(1);
   }
}
```